# Can we use ethernet cable instead of coaxial cable without adaptors.?

Tags: cables, signal-processing, camera, video, video-transmitter

I am a mechanical engineer. Trying to build a computer vision system using endoscopic camera. I have a camera with 4 pin input, 2 input pins for power supply of 5 volt and 2 input pins for video signal transmission. I am using a 2+1 coaxial cable for video signal and power supply transmission. My camera is continuously moving at a certain speed, which causes the coaxial cables to break from inside. Since my application needs a robust cable with smaller dimension, around 4mm OD, I want to change the cable to CAT5 OR Unitronic FD Lapp cables (which has high torsional strength).   [image: Analog camera with led arrays and 4 pin input]

Can I use a cat 5 or other simple multicore cables instead of coaxial cable.? Why should I use only coaxial cable? I like to simply substitute the coaxial center strand and insulation with normal multicore cable. Will it work efficiently in long run ? I have tried an experiment, video signals where getting transmitted but suddenly the camera does not work. Dont know what has gone wrong with the camera.

Kindly suggest a possible solution. Thank you very much !

Comment: You'll need a balun at least. Not only are you going from an unbalanced coaxial cable to a balanced cat5e/cat6 cable, you are probably changing impedances as well.

Comment: Are you currently using a flex-rated coaxial cable?  They do exist for a reason.

Comment: @ chris Knudsen: I am sorry for my poor knowledge in electrical. I dont think I am using a flex rated cable. I using a simple 3+1 cable that is used for any CCTV Camera available in market

Comment: @ Felthry: Is it possbile to get same impedence as coaxial cable in cat5e or any other cables ?

Comment: Look for RG179 cable like [this one](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/F-Male-to-F-Male-Connector-TV-Pigtail-cable-RG179-75ohm-1m-2m-3m-5m/32875815732.html). It's strong but very flexible. You can supply power separately with silicone pair

Comment: @Maple I'm afraid to ask what you mean by a "silicone pair". Should it be silicon instead? And did you mean a pair of transistors?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson two additional wires in silicon insulation since RG179 is not a 3+1. It was a typo

Comment: @Felthry : Can you please tell what is the function of balun ? and the difference between balanced and unbalanced cable as you mentioned

Comment: @SomaSundaram A balun converts between balanced and unbalanced cable, and also between cable impedances. With high frequency signalling, any mismatch in impedance causes signals to get reflected, reducing your signal strength and worsening your SNR.

Comment: @SomaSundaram Balanced cable has two identical conductors for the positive and negative signal wires; unbalanced cable doesn't. Coaxial cable is unbalanced because one of the conductors is a thin wire and the other is a cylindrical shell. Twisted pair cable like cat5e and cat6 is balanced, because the two wires in each pair are identical.

Comment: @Felthry: Thanks for the clear explanation. So basically, I will end up reducing signal strength and also will increase the noise, if I am using a balanced cable instead of unbalanced cable. Am I right?

Comment: @Felthry: Sorry to ask to you the same question again. In case, if I am happy with my SNR, I mean with the clarity of the video that I see in the screen while using the balanced cable, can this cable be a substitute for my coaxial ? I am really struggling to get a heavy duty (take high load,torsion and twist) coaxial cable along with power supply with in 6mm OD. But I can get the same with balanced cable easily .. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For motion applications, one should really use "flex-rated" cables.  It really does not take long for 'typical' cables to fail when exposed to repetitive motion applications.

Flex cables are expensive, but they will solve your problem.  Patching in other cable types may give you a bit more longevity, but the cables will still fail.

Flex-rated cables are designed such that not only the inner conductors last longer (more/finer strands, and additional non-conductive elements), but also the outer jackets can slide against each other and not chafe as much.

Flex cables are available for single and multi-conductor cords, as well as coaxial cable.  You can find them by searching for "Flex cables" or "continuous motion cables".